# Pushed to the wrong branch and want to repush to the correct branch

Tags: git, github

I checked out a commit to a new branch locally.  But when I pushed my changes I pushed it using git push origin  but realized I specified the wrong branch name and it ended up creating a new branch with that branch name on the remote repo.

Since I committed those changes on a new branch, is there a way to reverse this so I can commit again to the right remote branch?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the remote branch you just created by mistake, you can use the following syntax (note the colon):

```
git push origin :branchname
```

The remote branch with the name `branchname` will be deleted. Your local branch with the same name stays intact.